# Variadic arguments and function pointers vector

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I'm facing an almost-logical problem while working on C++11.

I have a class I have to plot (aka draw a trend) and I want to exclude all the points which do not satisfy a given condition.
The points are of the class `Foo` and all the conditional functions are defined with the signature `bool Foo::Bar(Args...) const` where `Args...` represents a number of parameters (e.g. upper and lower limits on the returned value).

Everything went well up to the moment I wished to apply a single condition to the values to plot. Let's say I have a `FooPlotter` class which has something like:

```
template<class ...Args> GraphClass FooPlotter::Plot([...],bool (Foo::*Bar)(Args...), Args... args)
```

Which will iterate over my data container and apply the condition `Foo::*Bar` to all the elements, plotting the values which satisfy the given condition.

So far so good.

At a given point I wanted to pass a vector of conditions to the same method, in order to use several conditions to filter data.

I first created a class to contain everything I need to have later:

```
    template<class ...Args> class FooCondition{
        public:
            FooCondition(bool (Foo::*Bar)(Args...) const, Args... args)
            {
                fCondition = Bar;
                fArgs = std::make_tuple(args);
            }
            bool operator()(Foo data){ return (data.*fCondition)(args); }
        private:
            bool (Foo::*fCondition)(Args...) const;
            std::tuple<Args...> fArgs;
    };
```

Then I got stuck on how to define a (iterable) container which can contain `FooCondition` objects despite them having several types for the `Args...` arguments pack.
The problem is that some methods have `Args... = uint64_t,uint_64_t` while others require no argument to be called.

I digged a bit on how to handle this kind of situation. I tried several approaches, but none of them worked well.

For the moment I added ignored arguments to all the `Bar` methods, uniformising them and working-around the issue, but I am not really satisfied!

Has some of you an idea on how to store differently typed `FooCondition` objects in an elegant way?

---

EDIT: Additional information on the result I want to obtain.

First I want to be able to create a `std::vector` of `FooCondition` items:

```
    std::vector<FooCondition> conditions;
    conditions.emplace_back(FooCondition(&Foo::IsBefore, uint64_t timestamp1));
    conditions.emplace_back(FooCondition(&Foo::IsAttributeBetween, double a, double b));
    conditions.emplace_back(FooCondition(&Foo::IsOk));
```

At this point I wish I can do something like the following, in my `FooPlotter::Plot` method:

```
    GraphClass FooPlotter::Plot(vector<Foo> data, vector<FooCondition> conditions){
        GraphClass graph;
        for(const auto &itData : data){
            bool shouldPlot = true;
            for(const auto &itCondition : conditions){
                shouldPlot &= itCondition(itData);
            }
            if(shouldPlot) graph.AddPoint(itData);
        }
        return graph;
    }
```

As you can argue the `FooCondition struct` should pass the right arguments to the method automatically using the overloaded operator.

Here the issue is to find the correct container to be able to create a collection of `FooCondition` templates despite the size of their arguments pack.

Comment: maybe a tuple? Anyway, isn't clear to me what do you exactly want; I suggest to show a practical example of what do you want obtain.

Comment: I have added some information. I hope this helps clarifying the question! Thanks

Comment: I still cannot understand your writing, can you please rephrase? Thank you!

Comment: I see... I understand a little more... I have an half idea... let me think a little...

Comment: Another question... variadic templates, so at least C++11; but C++11, C++14 or C++17?

Comment: As stated in the main post I have to comply with C++11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that, with `FooCondition` you're trying to create a substitute for a `std::function<bool(Foo *)>` (or maybe `std::function<bool(Foo const *)>`) initialized with a `std::bind` that fix some arguments for `Foo` methods.

I mean... I think that instead of

```
std::vector<FooCondition> conditions;
conditions.emplace_back(FooCondition(&Foo::IsBefore, uint64_t timestamp1));
conditions.emplace_back(FooCondition(&Foo::IsAttributeBetween, double a, double b));
conditions.emplace_back(FooCondition(&Foo::IsOk));
```

you should write something as

```
std::vector<std::function<bool(Foo const *)>> vfc;

using namespace std::placeholders;

vfc.emplace_back(std::bind(&Foo::IsBefore, _1, 64U));
vfc.emplace_back(std::bind(&Foo::IsAttributeBetween, _1, 10.0, 100.0));
vfc.emplace_back(std::bind(&Foo::IsOk, _1));
```

The following is a simplified full working C++11 example with a `main()` that simulate `Plot()`

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Foo
 {
   double  value;

   bool IsBefore (std::uint64_t ts) const
    { std::cout << "- IsBefore(" << ts << ')' << std::endl; 
      return value < ts; }

   bool IsAttributeBetween (double a, double b) const
    { std::cout << "- IsAttrributeBetwen(" << a << ", " << b << ')'
         << std::endl; return (a < value) && (value < b); }

   bool IsOk () const
    { std::cout << "- IsOk" << std::endl; return value != 0.0; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   std::vector<std::function<bool(Foo const *)>> vfc;

   using namespace std::placeholders;

   vfc.emplace_back(std::bind(&Foo::IsBefore, _1, 64U));
   vfc.emplace_back(std::bind(&Foo::IsAttributeBetween, _1, 10.0, 100.0));
   vfc.emplace_back(std::bind(&Foo::IsOk, _1));

   std::vector<Foo> vf { Foo{0.0}, Foo{10.0}, Foo{20.0}, Foo{80.0} };

   for ( auto const & f : vf )
    {
      bool  bval { true };

      for ( auto const & c : vfc )
         bval &= c(&f);

      std::cout << "---- for " << f.value << ": " << bval << std::endl;
    }
 }
```

Another way is avoid the use of `std::bind` and use lambda function instead.

By example

```
std::vector<std::function<bool(Foo const *)>> vfc;

vfc.emplace_back([](Foo const * fp)
                 { return fp->IsBefore(64U); });
vfc.emplace_back([](Foo const * fp)
                 { return fp->IsAttributeBetween(10.0, 100.0); });
vfc.emplace_back([](Foo const * fp)
                 { return fp->IsOk(); });
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! I am trying your solution and I will report asap :)

Comment: Your solution did the trick, I created a little container class which wraps around your solution using lambda functions (which allow me to negate the condition by returning condition == !negate).
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

All of the foo bar aside you just need a class with a method which can be implemented to satisfy the plot.

Just add a Plot method on the class which accepts the node and perform the transformation and plotting in the same step.

You need not worry about args when plotting because each function knows what arguments it needs.

Thus a simple args* will suffice and when null no arguments, therein each arg reveals it's type and value or can be assumed from the function invocation.

Comment: I don't think I got the point of your answer and I cannot really understand what you wrote. Can you rephrase a bit?